# How can I access historical data from HomeKit sensors -- or alternatively log this data myself

Tags: homekit

I have an outside and inside temperature sensor on HomeKit.
Recently I ran into the problem that I wanted to check the temperatures a couple of days ago.
As far as I have been able to determine, there does not seem to be a way to get historical data from HomeKit.

As an alternative, would it be possible to log homekit data yourself?
I know that iOS apps can request access to HomeKit data, so that could be one way to go about it.
However I would prefer to do this also when my phone is switched off / without network. Is there a (web)API that I can call in order to get access to this data from (say) a Raspberry PI, so that I can log this data on regular intervals?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is indeed [no way to access historical data from Homekit devices](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/27479) (unless you're able to do so though the device-maker's cloud).

As far as I know there is NO way to get to HomeKit data if you're not an iOS/macOS device.
Four years ago [Homekit opened up the devices-end](https://diyprojects.io/apple-opens-homekit-to-makers-and-non-commercial-enterprise-projects/#.YOK_sS0Rpqs) so that third party devices could be used.
There does not seem to be a similar move on the controller/reader end.

iOS apps can only [access data while they run in the foreground](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651553) -- supposedly for security and privacy reasons (good reasons as far as I'm concerned :) ). So unless you have an iOS device lying around that you're willing to sacrifice for this, this is a no go.
Possibly you could get this to work on a mac that is running 24/7; I'm not sure what the restrictions are there.

There is something you can do if you want to log this data.
Using [Shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/welcome/ios) for Home, you can have a small Shortcut-program run on your home hub (usually Apple TV or HomePod).
You will have access to [fewer commands](https://linkdhome.com/articles/Shortcuts-in-homekit) than in full (iOS) Shortcuts, however thing you *can* do is read out the value for HomeKit devices, and make HTTPS (post) calls.

The iOS Home app unfortunately only allows you to schedule this shortcut to run once a day, however using the third party (free) [Eve app](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/eve-for-homekit/id917695792) you schedule it to run once every 5 minutes.
Just make sure you *start* with setting up the timer, and only *then* transform it into a shortcut -- because of bugs/limitations of the way Apple works, it doesn't seem to work the other way round.

I did a [writeup](https://blog.claude.nl/tech/howto/logging-homekit-data-to-google-sheets-for-free-walkthrough/) of this whole process a couple of days ago, including a way to post the data to a Google Sheet, for a 100% free solution.

[image: Example Google Sheets with Homekit log]

Comment: Nice one! I think the critical point is the Eve app.

Comment: Yeah, it’s crazy that this obviously is available in the api, but not in the home app itself…

Comment: great overview @Claude...is it still up2date?

Comment: As far as I know, it still works (see comments on the [blog page](https://blog.claude.nl/tech/howto/logging-homekit-data-to-google-sheets-for-free-walkthrough/), people seem to be using it regularly). It may be that things get easier with Matter (I'm doing a deep-dive into Matter myself at the moment; but there is a lot of it!), when I know more I'll update stuff!

Comment: @Claude any updates to your efforts w matter?

Comment: @Shackrock I keep meaning to write a proper update on how to do it with Matter, and life keeps getting in the way. Anyways, as fas as I understand right now (but untested) it should be possible to add a Matter Controller (which means your devices will have two controllers, the Homepod and a matter controller. This controller can then do whatever you want (e.g. read and log data). Note however that this only works for matter compatible devices, not for homekit only devices.